# Rails app validation error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am running a rails app on Heroku and running into a problem when a user tries to reset their password.  My User model has `validates_uniqueness_of :email` and the method to reset their password is

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```

When I check `heroku logs` it is telling me that the `save!` is generating `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email has already been taken)`, however I'm not creating a new User or even editing the current user's email field.
When I run it locally everything works fine with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there are more than one user with the same email in the database.

It's possible that the duplicate was created before the validation was added.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I added a couple users with the same email before I added that validation.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Db, use `heroku run console` to connect to your application's console and look at the output of `User.all` to see if it's there. It won't be the fact that you are running this on Heroku that's causing this error.